# popup modal closed when select option or input field is clicked

Tags: html, css

i am getting a problem in popup modal when i click on something like select option or input field or button then popup modal closed imidiately.I am trying to fix but not getting any solution.is that bootstrap plugin issue or something else? anyone tell me please why this problem come and how to fix that?

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 search_resp" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#searchresp" 
    style="border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px grey;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 30px;">
                  <div style="display: flex;
                   width: 100%; padding: 0px 15%;">
                  
                    <div style="width: 55px;
                     padding: 10px 0px;">
                    <img src="img/more.png" style="height: 55px;width: 55px;filter: 
                      brightness(1.3);">
                  </div>
                  <div style="padding: 25px 0px;

                   text-align: center;
                    width: 100%;">
                     <h2>
                       <span class="toggle-search-button" style="color: #13216e;">Search 
                        Filters</span>
                     </h2>
                   </div>
                  
                  </div> 

          <div class="modal fade" id="searchresp" role="dialog" aria- 
           labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog" role="document" style="    width: 100%;
               margin: 30px auto;">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px darkslategray;">
    <div class="modal-header" style="display: block; border-bottom: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times; 
        </button>
      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="margin-top: -20px;">
      <div class="row mt-10-resp">



                <!-- Property For -->

                <div class="feilds_width ml-0">

                    <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <select class="selectpicker form-control bg-clr-w r_mrgn" 
                         id="property_for" name="property_for" 
                         onchange="popup_fun(this.value); 
                    change_search_btn_res('p_for', this.value)" required>

                            <option value="" disabled>Property For</option>

                            <option value="Sale" selected>Sale</option>

                            <option value="Rent">Rent</option>

                            <option value="Projects">Projects</option>

                        </select>

                    </fieldset>

                </div>



                <!-- Country -->

                <div class="feilds_width">

                    <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <select class="selectpicker form-control bg-clr-w r_mrgn" id="country" 
                         name="country" size="auto" data-live-search="true" 
                         onchange="change_search_btn_res('country', this.value)">

                            <option value="">Country</option>



                            <?php

                            $countries = $db->get('countries',null,'country_name');

                            foreach($countries as $key) {

                                ?>



                                <option value="<?php echo $key['country_name']; ?>" <?php 
                                 if($key['country_name'] == $user_country) echo 'selected'; ? 
                                  >><?php echo $key['country_name']; ?></option>



                            <?php } ?>



                        </select>

                    </fieldset>

                </div>



                <!-- City -->

                <div class="feilds_width">

                    <fieldset class="form-group">

                        <div class="form-group label-floating fl-title city_field">

                            <label class="control-label">City</label>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control list-city-field border- 
                             radius-0" id="city" name="city" 
                              onkeyup="change_search_btn_res('city', this.value)">

                        </div>

                    </fieldset>

                </div>



                <!-- Other Filters -->

                <div class="feilds_width form-group">

                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-md list-filter-btn border- 
                      radius-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#filter_modal" data- 
                     placement="top">Other Filters</a>

                </div>

            </div> 

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="border-top: none;">
    <!-- Search Button -->

        <div class="feilds_width form-group">

            <button class="btn btn-md list-search-btn list-search-empty-btn br-0" 
             type="button" id="search_btn_res" name="search_btn"                        
             onclick="get_result_res('get_list_property_project_data.php')">Search</button>

        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```